# Incompatibility issues in some browsers on this audio player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to this web page, which I am integrating, I would like to help me in these codes of an author that was taken from a page. This is an audio player and what happens works well in Mozilla Firefox, but in Google Chrome, does not give the audio and also the CSS style does not go well in Google Chrome and I suppose it is in the encoding of JavaScript and As also the interface "possibly" is destabilizing, since it does not come out the same as the Mozilla that is perfect.

Also this programming I want to do in "Responsive" and also a list of songs, which would be a luminous text above the play, the progress bar and the speaker, but that has a hidden slider, which click opens but I do not know If the coding can be improved .... Or create a new one in either CSS or JavaScript.

Here the code:

## JavaScript:

```
  var audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = 'Put the mp3 audio path here';
  audio.controls = true;
  audio.loop = false;
  audio.autoplay = true;

  var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;
  window.addEventListener("load", initMp3Player, false);

  function initMp3Player(){
  document.getElementById('audio_box').appendChild(audio);
  context = new AudioContext();
  analyser = context.createAnalyser();
  canvas = document.getElementById('analyser_render');
  /*canvas = _('analyser_render');*/
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  source.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(context.destination);
  frameLooper();
  }

function frameLooper(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
    fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';
    bars = 100;
    for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++){
        bar_x = i * 3;
        bar_width = 2;
        bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 5);

        ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
    }
 }
```

## HTML:

```
<span class="cajamp3">
 <div id="mp3_player">
            <div id="audio_box"></div>
            <canvas id="analyser_render"></canvas>
 </div>  
</span>
```

## CSS:

```
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div#mp3_player{ 
    float: left;        
    width: 290px;
    height: 65px;
    background: #000;
    padding: 5px;       
}

div#mp3_player > div > audio{
    width: 270px;
    background: #000;
    float: left;
}

div#mp3_player > canvas{
    width: 270px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #002D3C;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: `in Google Chrome, does not give the audio` - what **does** hapen in Chrum? do you get any errors in the **developer** tools console that could help? There's nothing obviously wrong in your JS, HTML or CSS, and nothing that shouldn't work identically in Chrum and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Ok, The problem is in JavaScript, because in the part that says "source = context.createMediaElementSource (audio);", for Firefox, it works wonderfully, instead running Chrome audio is not heard, but the time bar is still But if I change it to "source = context.MediaElementSource (audio);", automatically as much as CHROME and FIREFOX work fine, even though it works: "FUNCTION FRAMELOOPER", the frequency levels in the FIREFOX browser do not work, and I do not know why.

Forgive me for forgetting to tell you where the error is, and also as I am new I did not know how to do a test.

But I want to do as "responsive", which I tried to do with a DIV and that within it will perform the "responsive", but still does not work.

Thanks I hope your prompt response.